# NSTableColumn size to fit contents

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, user-interface, nstableview

I am developing in and against Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard). When I double-click between two of my NSTableView's column headers, the column on the left autosizes, like you would expect.

I want to provide this in a context menu as well, but it seems there is no publicly accessible function to do this. I've Googled, and looked at the documentation for NSTableView, NSTableHeaderView, and NSTableColumn, but found nothing. I find it hard to believe they wouldn't expose something so useful when they obviously have the code written to do it.

I saw the `-[NSTableColumn sizeToFit]` method, but that only takes the header's size into account. I would also settle for sending the double-click event to the NSTableHeaderView, but couldn't figure out how to do that, either.

**Update** - I realized it's important to mention I have an NSArrayController (subclass) providing the data to my table, so I don't have an `NSTableViewDataSource` on which I could call `-[tableView: objectValueForTableColumn: row:]`. That is the crux of the problem: each column is bound to a keypath of the array controller and that's how it gets its data, so it can't loop through its contents.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the length of each cell by getting the cells from the column.

```
NSCell myCell = [column dataCellForRow:i];
```

Then get the width of the cell.

```
width = [myCell cellSize].width;
```

After that you can set the width of the cell as the width of the column.

```
[column setMinWidth:width];
[column setWidth:width];
```

Comment: dataCellForRow just returns the column's dataCell in the default implementation, which has the column's width: (Apple Docs) http://tinyurl.com/5r8yprj

Comment: The dataCell obtained in this way has the cell width. Actually, I pasted the above code from one of my program. You can see a sneak peek of my program here: http://www.screencast.com/t/4UB3NGPxH4 .

I used a NSTableView on a floating NSPanel. The width of the window and the table view changes with the width of the largest cell in the column.

Comment: You are totally correct, the data cell does return the greatest width of all the cells in the column.

Comment: Note that for view-based table views, `dataCellForRow` will not return the correct cell. See [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14677130/632555) for how to do it with view-based table views.

Comment: Apple's autosizing method uses `[NSTableView preparedCellAtColumn:row:]` rather than `[NSTableColumn dataCellForRow:]`. Also, they randomly sample the table if it has a large number of rows, rather than iterating through all rows. (See the docs for the table view delegate method `tableView:sizeToFitWidthOfColumn:`)

Answer (score 7):

The following category on NSTableColumn resizes columns to the same width that double-clicking on the separator would produce.

```
@implementation NSTableColumn (resize)

- (void) resizeToFitContents
{
    NSTableView * tableView = self.tableView;
    NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(0,0, INFINITY, tableView.rowHeight);
    NSInteger columnIndex = [tableView.tableColumns indexOfObject:self];
    CGFloat maxSize = 0;
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < tableView.numberOfRows; i++) {
        NSCell *cell = [tableView preparedCellAtColumn:columnIndex row:i];
        NSSize size = [cell cellSizeForBounds:rect];
        maxSize = MAX(maxSize, size.width);
    }
    self.width = maxSize;
}

@end
```

Comment: Works for me but I still have to add about `8` points to `size.width`, otherwise the very last character of the longest entry gets cut off and replaced by `...`. This fact makes me somewhat uncomfortable because of course I don't want to hard-code values like `8` anywhere because obviously, this might only be the right value for my specific system with my specific font and font size involved. So this answer still doesn't seem perfect...

Answer (score 6):

For view-based table views (OS X 10.7 and later), you have to use the `NSTableView` method `viewAtColumn:row:makeIfNecessary:`, and then get the size.

The following code works if your cell view is an `NSTextField`. For other views you have to figure out the way to get its minimum size.

```
[tableView.tableColumns enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:
    ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSTableColumn* column = (NSTableColumn*) obj;
        CGFloat width = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < tableView.numberOfRows; row++) {
            NSView* view = [tableView viewAtColumn: idx
                row: row
                makeIfNecessary: YES];
            NSSize size = [[view cell] cellSize];
            width = MAX(width, MIN(column.maxWidth, size.width));
        }
        column.width = width;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Where exactly can I call this?

Comment: In your controller, whenever you think that the columns need to be resized.

Comment: Actually, thats where I am a bit confused. You see I have 8 columns out of which 6 are NSTextField and two are NSImageView. The first problem I see with above code is NSSize size = [[view cell] cellSize];. xcode complains that cell method may not respond. I replaced the above line with NSSize size = view.frame.size; I am not sure if its correct. Secondly I populate my table (add objects to array) and call [ltableView reloadData]; I thought If I call your code just before the reloadData it would help. But it just reduces all columns to minimum.

Comment: I also tried calling it when a row gets added - (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView didAddRowView:(NSTableRowView *)rowView forRow:(NSInteger)row and no effect. Can you help?

Comment: As I wrote originally, the example only works for `NSTextField`; for other types of cells you will need to adapt the size discovery logic. As for when, you should be able to do this any time after setting up the table, eg. after assigning a `dataSource`.

Comment: Just for people's sake who are using Swift, you can't grab a cell for a view (it doesn't seem to have that property available to it). You can however grab the cell for a view's textfield (which is what we're dealing with here). It looks like:
`var size = view.textField?.cell()?.cellSize.width;
width = max(width, min(column.maxWidth, size!)); `

Answer (score 6):

I found the following to work for me (written in Swift):

```
func resizeColumn(columnName: String) {
    var longest:CGFloat = 0 //longest cell width
    let columnNumber = tableView.columnWithIdentifier(columnName)
    let column = tableView.tableColumns[columnNumber] as! NSTableColumn
    for (var row = 0; row < tableView.numberOfRows; row++) {
        var view = tableView.viewAtColumn(columnNumber, row: row, makeIfNecessary: true) as! NSTableCellView
        var width = view.textField!.attributedStringValue.size.width

        if (longest < width) {
            longest = width
        }
    }

    column.width = longest
    viewTable.reloadData()
}
```

Given a column's identifier as an argument, it finds the cell in that column with the longest content, and resizes the column to fit that content.

Comment: It did not return the length based on the string length, but instead the current width of the cell (set through Interface Builder), so my cell column was not being resized appropriately. This code actually examined the content of the cell and discovered the longest content string and resized based on that.

Comment: This solution is not efficient and not as fast as the behavior in the Finder app if the table contains hundreds of rows.

Comment: I found a faster implementation and posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72332567/10654098

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do this very thing and it turned out (for me at least) to be a bit more involved; this isn't perfect but pretty close ;-) 
p.s. Edited to handle image based cells

```
#define GBLBIN(x)   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:(x)]

- (IBAction)autosizeColumns:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableArray * widths = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSIndexSet * rows = [table selectedRowIndexes];
    NSArray * columns = [table tableColumns];
    BOOL deslectAll = NO;
    NSNumber * col = nil;
    int i, j;

    //  If no row's selected, then select all, the default
    if (![rows count])
    {
        [table selectAll:sender];
        rows = [table selectedRowIndexes];
        deslectAll = YES;
    }

    //  Use the selected rows from which we'll use the columns' formatted data widths
    for (i=[rows lastIndex]; i != NSNotFound; i=[rows indexLessThanIndex:i])
    {
        for (j=0; j<[columns count]; j++)
        {
            NSTableColumn * column = [columns objectAtIndex:j];
            id item = [[table dataSource]
                tableView:table objectValueForTableColumn:column row:i];
            NSCell * cell = [column dataCell];
            float width, minWidth=10;

            //  Depending on the dataCell type (image or text) get the 'width' needed
            if ([cell isKindOfClass:[NSTextFieldCell class]])
            {
                NSFont * font = ([cell font]
                    ? [cell font] : [NSFont controlContentFontOfSize:(-1)]);
                NSDictionary * attrs = 
                    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
                NSFormatter * formatter = [cell formatter];
                NSString * string = item;

                //  We want a string, as IB would have formatted it...
                if (![item isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
                    if (formatter)
                        string = [formatter stringForObjectValue:item];
                    else
                        string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", item];

                width = [string sizeWithAttributes:attrs].width + minWidth;
            }
            else
            {
                //  We have NSButtonCell, NSImageCell, etc; get object's width
                width = MAX(minWidth,[[cell image] size].width);
            }

            //  First time seeing this column, go with minimum width
            if (j == [widths count])
            {
                [widths addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:minWidth]];
            }
            col = [widths objectAtIndex:j];
            width = MAX([col floatValue], width);
            [widths replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:width]];
        }
    }

    //  Now go resize each column to its minimum data content width
    for (j=0; j<[widths count]; j++)
    {
        NSTableColumn * column = [columns objectAtIndex:j];
        float width = [[widths objectAtIndex:j] floatValue];

        if (GBLBIN(@"debug"))
        {
            NSLog(@"col:%d '%@' %.f", j, [column identifier], width);
        }
        [column setWidth:width];
    }

    //  Undo select all if we did it
    if (deslectAll)
    {
        [table deselectAll:sender];
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a _lot_ more complicated than the accepted answer. What issues with that approach were you attempting to work around?

Comment: Yes it is complicated. Hmmm maybe my solution is to a different issue / question.  My issue which appeared similar to theirs, was to autosize columns to their columns' data content. If you feel there's a simpler solution, please do post it.  Of course my issue might be obscure but hopefully the solution posted isn't unduly complex.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some extension methods to size columns by their content in C# for Monomac developers.

**NOTE:** this sizes columns by their content only, other considerations no considered (empty cols are 10px wide for eg).

Thanks to slashlos for the obj-c snippet.

```
public static void SizeColumnsByContent(this NSTableView tableView, int minWidth = 10) {
        Contract.Requires(tableView != null);
        Contract.Requires(tableView.DataSource != null);
        var columns = tableView.TableColumns();
        var widths = new List<int>();
        for (int row=0; row< tableView.RowCount; row++) {
            for (int col=0; col < tableView.ColumnCount; col++) {
                // Determine what the fit width is for this cell
                var column = columns[col];
                var objectValue = tableView.DataSource.GetObjectValue(tableView, column, row);
                var width = column.DataCell.DetermineFitWidth(objectValue, minWidth);

                // Record the max width encountered for current coolumn
                if (row == 0) {
                    widths.Add(width);
                } else {
                    widths[col] = Math.Max(widths[col], width);
                }
            }

            //  Now go resize each column to its minimum data content width
            for (int col=0; col < tableView.ColumnCount; col++) {
                columns[col].Width = widths[col];
            }
        }
    }

    public static int DetermineFitWidth(this NSCell cell, NSObject objectValueAtCell, int minWidth = 10) {
        int width;
        if (cell is NSTextFieldCell) {
            var font = cell.Font ?? NSFont.ControlContentFontOfSize(-1);
            var attrs = NSDictionary.FromObjectAndKey(font, NSAttributedString.FontAttributeName);

            // Determine the text on the cell
            NSString cellText;
            if (objectValueAtCell is NSString) {
                cellText = (NSString)objectValueAtCell;
            } else if (cell.Formatter != null) {
                cellText = cell.Formatter.StringFor(objectValueAtCell).ToNSString();
            } else {
                cellText = objectValueAtCell.Description.ToNSString();
            }

            width = (int)cellText.StringSize(attrs).Width + minWidth;

        } else if (cell.Image != null) {
            // if cell has an image, use that images width
            width = (int)Math.Max(minWidth, (int)cell.Image.Size.Width);
        }  else {
            // cell is something else, just use its width
            width = (int)Math.Max(minWidth, (int)cell.CellSize.Width);
        }

        return width;

    }
```

Comment: Does the accepted answer not work in Monomac? I would think it should, and it's a lot simpler.

Comment: Monomac is C#, not obj-C. What I provided is just a (cleaned up) version of the answer in C#.

Comment: You're providing a cleaned up version of the overly-complicated, more verbose, non-accepted Objective-C answer in C#. You can't make the same calls in C# that the accepted answer makes in Objective-C? That would only be roughly 4 lines of code (even in C#).

Comment: The accepted answer is wrong. The question wants to RESIZE the columns to fit their contents (that includes shrinking columns as well). The "complicated" answer is the pathway for more sophisticated "auto-sizing" functionality.

Comment: Did you try [C# equivalent of] the accepted answer? I accepted it because it did what I needed it to.

Comment: Your accepted answer won't shrink a table to fit its contents.

Comment: Have you actually tried it? It actually does shrink or grow the columns. I've been using the code for a while.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble implementing some of the other solutions... But I managed to get columns to automatically resize width when cells are created using the cell's string value. Seems to work pretty well so far!

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    NSString *identifier = [tableColumn identifier];
    NSUInteger col = [keys indexOfObject:identifier];

    // Get an existing cell with the MyView identifier if it exists
    NSTextField *cell = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:identifier owner:self];

    // Get cell data
    NSDictionary *dict = [self.tableContents objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *stringValue = [dict objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:col]]; 

    // There is no existing cell to reuse so create a new one
    if (cell == nil) {

        // Create the new NSTextField with a frame of the {0,0} with the width of the table.
        // Note that the height of the frame is not really relevant, because the row height will modify the height.
        NSRect rect = NSRectFromCGRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 24));
        cell = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        [cell setBordered:NO];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
        [cell setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];

        // autosize to fit width - update column min width
        NSRect rectAutoWidth = [stringValue boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){CGFLOAT_MAX, 24} options:NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading|NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:cell.font}]; 
        if ( tableColumn.minWidth < rectAutoWidth.size.width )
        {
            [tableColumn setMinWidth:rectAutoWidth.size.width+20]; // add padding
        }

        // The identifier of the NSTextField instance is set to MyView. This allows the cell to be reused.
        cell.identifier = identifier;
    }

    // result is now guaranteed to be valid, either as a reused cell or as a new cell, so set the stringValue of the cell to the nameArray value at row

    // set value
    cell.stringValue = stringValue;

    // Return the result
    return cell;
}
```