# Setting NSTableColumn width to exactly the size of its widest row

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I want to set the width of my `NSTableColumn` to the exact width of the widest entry so that the text doesn't get ellipsized by `...`. To do that, I'm doing the following whenever a new text entry is inserted:

```
NSCell *cell = [tableView preparedCellAtColumn:0 row:idx];
NSSize size = [cell cellSize];

if(size.width > widestWidth) {
    [tableColumn setWidth:size.width];
    widestWidth = size.width;
}
```

Unfortunately, the width returned by `cellSize` seems to be a few points off because the last character still gets ellipsized by `...`. I can easily solve the problem by just adding about 8 points to `size.width` but of course I want to avoid that because there might be different font configurations where 8 is not enough and I also want the `NSTableColumn`'s width to **perfectly** fit to that of its widest entry.

That's why I'd like to ask: How can I get the **exact** width of a row so that I can pass it to `NSTableColumn::SetWidth` so that the `NSTableColumn`'s width is exactly that of the widest row?

Comment: Try: 1. Get string as it is entered into table view. 2. Check bounding box with NSString:sizeWithAttributes. 3. Set column width accordingly if string too long to fit.

Comment: @apodidae: Doesn't work. The result of `sizeWithAttributes` is even less than what `cellSize` returns. For the string `Test item` I get 59 points from `cellSize` and 55 points from `sizeWithAttributes`.

Comment: Interesting that text will fit perfectly in a bounding box calculated by sizeWithAttributes, but not in a tableView column supposedly of the same width.

Comment: I think it's even weirder that the value returned by `cellSize` doesn't suffice.

Comment: But how can I get this padding value?

Comment: Yes, but how to compute that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSTableColumn size to fit contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674163/nstablecolumn-size-to-fit-contents)

Comment: @Willeke: It's similar but not the same. My problem was that I was casting `cellSize.width` to an integer without rounding. This led to the ellipsization because apparently, the decimals are important for `NSTableColumn`. When passing the result of `cellSize.width` to `setWidth` as a `CGFloat` it works fine. When using integers, however, I need to round up `cellSize.width` as described by apididae or there will be an ellipsization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the following example, it appears that [cell cellSize].width may be used to set the column width of a cell-based table view if the greatest cellSize.width is rounded up.  The source code may be run in Xcode by replacing 'main.m' with the following and deleting the pre-supplied AppDelegate.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

 @interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSTableViewDelegate,  NSTableViewDataSource> {
  NSWindow *window;
 }
 @property(strong, nonatomic) NSArray *teams;
 - (void) createMenu;
 - (void) createWindow;
 @end
 
 @implementation AppDelegate
 
- (id)init{
 if(self = [super init])
 _teams = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Ravens", @"Chiefs", @"Chargers", @"Bengals", nil];
 NSLog(@"teams = %@",_teams);
 return self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
 NSLog(@"count = %lu", [_teams count]);
 return [_teams count];
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
 NSString *team = [_teams objectAtIndex:row];
 NSLog(@"team = %@",team);
 return [_teams objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (NSCell *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView dataCellForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)col row:(NSInteger)row {
 NSTextFieldCell *cell = [col dataCell];
 [cell setBackgroundColor: [NSColor redColor]];
 [cell setDrawsBackground:YES];
 NSSize size = [cell cellSize];
 NSLog(@"cell width = %0.02f",size.width);
 return cell;
}

 - (void) createMenu {
 NSMenu *menubar = [NSMenu new];
 NSMenuItem *appMenuItem = [NSMenuItem new];
 [menubar addItem:appMenuItem];
 [NSApp setMainMenu:menubar];
 NSMenu *appMenu = [NSMenu new];
 NSMenuItem *quitMenuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Quit"
 action:@selector(terminate:) keyEquivalent:@"q"];
 [appMenu addItem:quitMenuItem];
 [appMenuItem setSubmenu:appMenu];
 }
 
 - (void) createWindow {
 #define _wndW  300
 #define _wndH  300
 window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect: NSMakeRect( 0, 0, _wndW, _wndH )
 styleMask: NSWindowStyleMaskTitled | NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable | NSWindowStyleMaskClosable backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered defer: NO];
 [window center];
 [window setTitle:@"Test window"];
 [window makeKeyAndOrderFront: nil];
 
// **** Table View with Scroll **** //
 NSScrollView * scrollView = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( 20, _wndH - 230, _wndW - 40, 200)];
 [scrollView setBorderType:NSBezelBorder];
 [scrollView setHasVerticalScroller:YES];
 [scrollView setAutohidesScrollers:YES];
 
 NSTableView *tableView = [[NSTableView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 180, 200)];
 NSTableColumn *column1 = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"Col1"];
 [[column1 headerCell] setStringValue:@"Teams"];
 //Change this to 59 to see ellipsis : longest [cell cellSize].width = 59.33
 [column1 setWidth: 60];
 [tableView addTableColumn:column1];
 [tableView setDelegate:self];
 [tableView setDataSource:self];
 [tableView reloadData];
 
 // **** Embed table view into scroll view, and add scroll view to window
 [scrollView setDocumentView:tableView];
 [[window contentView] addSubview:scrollView];
  
// ***** Quit btn ***** //
 NSButton *quitBtn = [[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( _wndW - 50, 5, 40, 40 )];
 [quitBtn setBezelStyle:NSBezelStyleCircular ];
 [quitBtn setTitle: @"Q" ];
 [quitBtn setAction:@selector(terminate:)];
 [[window contentView] addSubview: quitBtn];

 }
 
 - (void) applicationWillFinishLaunching: (NSNotification *)notification {
 [self createMenu];
 [self createWindow];
 }
 
 - (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching: (NSNotification *)notification {
 }
 @end
 
 int main() {
  NSApplication *application = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
  AppDelegate *myDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
  [application setDelegate:myDelegate];
  [application run];
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Indeed, just using `ceil()` on `size.width` solves the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

When I ran an old cell-based demo with manual reference counting and used method dataCellForTableColumn: to measure [cell cellSize].width I got the values shown in the first image for the array items listed.  When I set the column width to 60 (by rounding longest string length of 59.33 up) there was no problem.  When I set the col width to 59 (by rounding down) I got the ellipsis for Charge....  I can not explain why 'Bengals' has a greater cell width than 'Chargers'. The 'team' was taken from another method, objectValueForTableColumn: and my have something to do with the order in which they are called?  Second image shows the correct result by rounding up the greatest cell width.

[image]

[image]

I'll try and post the source if I ever get it converted to arc.